# elm-make.exe: getFileAttributesExStandard: does not exist

Tags: elm, elm-mdl

I followed the instructions to get the latest version of debois/elm-mdl [here](https://github.com/debois/elm-mdl/issues/348).

After using elm-github-install to install v9, my app does not want to compile any more. I get the following error:

> 11:42:35 PM client.1 | Module build failed: Error: Compiler process exited with error Compilation failed
>   11:42:35 PM client.1 | elm-make.exe: getFileAttributesExStandard: does not exist (The system cannot find the path specified.)

Comment: Did you try the instructions from [this comment](https://github.com/debois/elm-mdl/issues/348#issuecomment-323682343)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually what worked was to delete the elm-stuff folder and reinstall everything using elm-install.